# Find specific mail in Outlook by title

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, com-automation

I am trying to create a code that will find letters in my mailbox using Subject field (according Outlook rules this letters will be located in folder 'TODO' for example). 
That's what I have for now:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("TODO")

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.subject
print(body_content)
```

This code finds the last letter at the folder.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will search in all the messages of TODO folder and if the subject matches with the String to be searched, it will print found message

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("TODO")

messages = inbox.Items
    for message in messages:
        if message.subject == 'String To be Searched':
            print("Found message")
```

Comment: It returns error: 

    if message.subjectis is in 'S2S scale run for':
                                         ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Have replaced 'is in' with '==', for now it works, thanks!

Comment: Can you accept the answer? This helps the community!

Answer (score 1):

You **need** to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. For example, to get items with `Hello world` subject line you can to use the following code:

```
private void FindAllUnreadEmails(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
    string searchCriteria = "[Subject] = `Hello world`";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
    int counter = default(int);
    Outlook._MailItem mail = null;
    Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
    object resultItem = null;
    try
    {
        if (folder.UnReadItemCount > 0)
        {
            strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            folderItems = folder.Items;
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria);
            while (resultItem != null)
            {
                if (resultItem is Outlook._MailItem)
                {
                    counter++;
                    mail = resultItem as Outlook._MailItem;
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + 
                                          "\tSubject: " + mail.Subject);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem);
                resultItem = folderItems.FindNext();
            }
            if (strBuilder != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " 
                                 + folder.Name + " folder.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
    }
}
```

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also, you may find the [AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch) method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Read more about this method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.